# Timer в отдельном потоке. Как завершить?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, кроссплатформенность

Qt5.7 MSVC2015_64/GCC 5.4
GUI приложение.
Я хочу чтобы таймер отрабатывал в отдельном потоке.

В классе главной формы:

```
m_tmr = new Timer(1000); //класс поток для таймера
m_tmr->start();
connect(m_tmr, &Timer::sg_TimOut, this, &MainForm::updateByTimer, Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Сам таймер:

```
Timer::Timer(int interval) : 
m_interval(interval),
m_startFlag(true)
{

}

Timer::~Timer()
{
    //delete timer;
    //quit();
}        

void Timer::run()
{
    QTimer timer;
    connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Timer::sg_TimOut);
    connect(this, &Timer::timerStoped, &timer, &QTimer::stop);        

    if (m_startFlag)
        timer.start(m_interval);
    exec();

    //mit finished(this->thread());
}

void Timer::startTimer(int interval)
{
    m_interval = interval;
    m_startFlag = true;
    emit timerStarted(interval);
}

void Timer::stop()
{
    m_startFlag = false;
    emit timerStoped();
}

void Timer::quit()
{
    stop();
    QThread::quit();
}
```

на выходе программа выдает следующее?

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

Как это выйти из потока и удалить таймер?

Comment: Выносить таймер в отдельный поток имеет смысл если действие, выполняемое по таймеру, также выполняется в отдельном потоке, иначе нет смысла и проще оставить в основном

Comment: слот который соединяется с сигналом таймера (timeOut) должен выполняться в том же потоке что и таймер. Ведь когда таймер "счелкает" вся вьюшка замирает и это заметно. В этом методе происходит обновление данных с сервера. Нужно как то выйти за exec чтобы послать сигнал finished();

Comment: Если `sg_TimOut` это сигнал класса-таймера, то выполнение слота `MainForm::updateByTimer` выполняется в главном потоке, а в отдельном происходит только обновление таймера

Comment: Забыл поправить. там с флагом DirectConnection. Проверял по отладке, слот отрабатывает в отдельном потоке

Comment: С флагом DirectConnection да, будет отрабатывать в том потоке, который испустил сигнал. По теме - `Timer` это наследник от `QThread`?